# Simpler method for pooling integers

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, integer

I would like to be able to take integers from an array based on their availability.  When an available integer is selected then it becomes unavailable until it is given back.

While this follows a simple pool idea I think I have overcomplicated matters with my approach and would like some advice.

There are a number of key pool-like functions that I am implementing, including:

- Get the first available lowest integer
- Get all available integers in ascending order
- Get a particular integer from the array
- Give a particular integer back to the array to make it available again

For the first method I keep a tally of the available integers by incrementing a value each time a request for a integer is successfully called.  This value can then be used to determine the starting index for the available integers should they be sorted by their .IsAvailable boolean.

```
    public static int GetInteger()
    {
        // Get the next available integer
        int startIndex = integers.Length - numAvailableIntegers;

        var c = integers[startIndex];
        c.IsAvailable = false;

        // Sort the integers by availability
        Array.Sort(integers, SortIntegerAvailability.Comparer);

        numAvailableIntegers--;

        return c.Value;
    }
```

The problem here is that sorting by boolean value also requires sorting by ascending integer value afterwards.

```
class SortIntegerAvailability : IComparer<Integer>
{
    static IComparer<Integer> comparer = new SortIntegerAvailability();

    public int Compare(Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        if (a.IsAvailable == b.IsAvailable)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else return (a.IsAvailable == true) ? 1 : -1;
    }

    public static IComparer<Integer> Comparer
    {
        get { return comparer; }
    }
}
```

This led me to think that I am making this far too complicated and that there is a more elegant way of approaching this problem.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the integers sequential?  That is, does the array start populated with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc? or is it sparse like 2, 6, 26, 256, etc.?

Comment: Does it have to be an array? There are other structures that make it easier to get the result you want...

Comment: @Micah It is currently sequential.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek It doesn't have to be an array.

Comment: I don't know if it fits your use case, but you could just use `SortedDictionary<int, bool>` and remove from it when the integer is taken out. That way the dictionary would only hold the available integers, accessing 'next smallest int' is trivial (by calling `.First()`), etc etc. If you want the `IsAvailable` flag (so the `bool` value in the `KeyValuePair`), it's also doable, although with a little more work.

Comment: This seems like a potential approach for me to try.  I presume I can insert the integer when it becomes available again and avoid the need for an .IsAvailable flag altogether?

Comment: @user1423893 Exactly. It would simplify the whole approach greatly, if it is applicable to your particular case.

Comment: "based on their availability" you say, but availability to whom? Different threads...? Should it only be possible for the thread that requested an integer to return it? There are a lot of thing to take into concern here! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class IntegersGame
{
    private List<int> _sourceintegers;
    private List<int> _integers;
    public void Add(List<int> integers)
    {
        _sourceintegers = integers;
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _integers = _sourceintegers.Select(p => p).ToList();
        _integers.Sort();
    }

    public int GetFirst()
    {
        int ret = _integers.First();
        _integers.Remove(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    public List<int> GetAll()
    {
        return _integers;
    }

    public void Release(int des)
    {
        if (_sourceintegers.Contains(des))
        {
            _integers.Add(des);
            _integers.Sort();
        }
    }

    public int? Get(int source)
    {
        if(_sourceintegers.Contains(source) && (_integers.Contains(source))){
            _integers.Remove(source);
            return source;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the community @Izikon. Rather than posting another answer, just edit your current answer and add your code there. I would also recommend you take a look at the about and faq section of stackoverflow.

Comment: This also looks like another avenue to go down.  Thank you, Izikon.

Comment: I have a couple of issues with this reply: 1) It exposes the _integers field through the GetAll method. 2) The Get method does not remove the requested integer from the _integers. 3) The Add method should rather be called e.g. Init, since it doesn't add anything; it resets the _sourceIntegers as well as the pooled integers. (Actually, I would prefer to supply the source integers in the constuctor.) 4) The Select(p => p) part of _sourceintegers.Select(p => p).ToList() seems a bit unnecessary. 5) It does not compile...

Comment: Edited , forget ")" and remove. spacedoom for your remarks. 1) this is what it needs to do. 2) now it does. 3) it add the list of integers 4) the part of select is cloning the list 5) compiled and tested

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer.  After some much needed sleep I have since devised a very simple List<int> approach.  This handles an ascending order of integers very quickly with no need for fancy sort algorithms.  I can post this is someone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

why not just clone a simple integer array and pull the first item and resort the cloned array each cycle?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with something like this, then optimize it if you find performance to be a problem.  Depending on the size of your integer collection, this may be a very fast solution (for relatively small collection sizes) or very slow (for incredibly large collection sizes).

```
private class MyInteger
{
    public int Value;
    public bool Available;
    public void MyInteger(int value, bool available)
    {
        Value = value;
        Available = available;
    }
}
public class IntegerPool
{
    private IList<MyInteger> _integers = new List<MyInteger>();

    public void IntegerPool(List<int> startingCollection)
    {
        startingCollection.Sort();

        foreach (var integer in startingCollection)
        {
            _integers.Add(new MyInteger(integer, true));
        }
    }

    public int GetFirstAvailable()
    {
        foreach (var integer in _integers)
        {
            if (integer.Available)
            {
                integer.Available = false;
                return integer.Value;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("No more integers available.");
    }

    public IList<int> GetAllAvailable()
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        foreach (var integer in _integers)
        {
            if (integer.Available)
                list.Add(integer.Value);
        }

        return list;
    }

    public int? TryGetSpecific(int specific)
    {
        foreach (var integer in _integers)
        {
            if (integer.Value == specific)
            {
                if (!integer.Available)
                    return null;

                integer.Available = false;
                return integer.Value;
            }
        }

        throw new Exception("Integer not in collection.");
    }

    public void ReleaseInteger(int integerToBeReleased)
    {
        foreach (var integer in _integers)
        {
            if (integer.Value == integerToBeReleased)
            {
                integer.Available = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a workable solution.  I had something similar written down but didn't want to implement it as it seemed like a brute force type of approach.